# Find the value of $x$, I can't move forward with the second algebraic translation

Tags: calculus

Triple a number minus $18$ is equal to twice the sum of its additive inverse plus $6$. Find the number.

I deduced the first part which is:

$$3x-18$$

But the second part has me confused, I don't know how to formulate it

Comment: The additive inverse of $x$ is $-x$.

Comment: twice the sum will be of the form $2(a+b)$.

Comment: That additive inverse is -3x+18?

Comment: Actually I think you have a very good point there -- the question is ambiguous due to the use of the pronoun "it". I'm fairly sure "it" was meant to be "the original number", based on the way questions like this are often set, but if you just follow the grammar it could be "triple a number minus $18$". I would still advise following the more likely interpretation, where "its additive inverse" is just $-x.$

Comment: Also, make sure you put commas. "Triple a number, minus 18" means $3x-18$. "Triple a number minus 18" can be interpreted as $3(x-18)$.

Answer (score 2):

The other side of the equality is $2(-x+6)$